# Keep :hover effect when hovering over another :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kysusekf/), while you hovering over `text-content`; the `opacity img` and the `img` classes return to a normal state, and I would like to keep `:hover` from `img` and `img opacity` while hovering over `text-content`.

Also I would like to know how to set the `background-color` of image's background.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="img-list">
    <li>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="modernTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 175px; height: 80px; background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.1);">
                    <section class="opacity">
                        <img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/TrwyFfT.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px; width: 175px; height: 79px;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span class="text-content">This will show up</span></span></section>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.opacity img {
    opacity:0.7;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.opacity img:hover {
    opacity:1;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
img {
    background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
img:hover {
    background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
ul.img-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.img-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 79px;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 175px;
}
span.text-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 175px;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px dashed transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
span.text-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What you want is impossible with CSS alone. I recommend jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is not possible in my case, any Javascript solutions?

Comment: @user3734782 Anything that is doable in jQuery is also possible with JavaScript, since jQuery is a library built entirely on top of JavaScript

Comment: I would like the JS solution ;)

Comment: It appears I didn't read your question clearly enough and assumed you wanted to keep the hoverstate forever, rather than just on a specific different element. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using only CSS. It *does* rearrange a bit of your HTML and CSS, though, because I felt you had a bit too much going on. I have provided a simplified solution that should be transferable to whatever markup you're using without much/any difficulty.

With the exact markup that you provided, the effect was not possible because the child element was removed from the normal document flow, thanks to `position: absolute;`. The key to keeping a parent element's hover state active when hovering over its child is to make sure the child is still within the parent's box model (and, therefore, "within the flow").

The below implementation differs from yours visually only in that the "grey" background extends downward to cover the child `span` element.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kysusekf/2/)**

```css
.opacity img:hover {
    opacity:1;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
img {
    opacity:0.7;
    background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
img:hover {
    background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.text-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 20px;
    width: 175px;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px dashed transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.opacity:hover .text-content {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.opacity:hover img {
    background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<table align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="modernTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-color: transparent; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 175px; height: 80px; background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.1);">
                <section class="opacity">
                    <img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/TrwyFfT.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px; width: 175px; height: 79px;" /><span class="text-content">This will show up</span>
                </section>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you also help me with this?
There's JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zn4cymdh/
*Ignore margin & paddings; they're fine in my website*
The problem is, when I add another <div class=box> it appears over the first one and I would like to place them in row.
Thanks.

Comment: @user3734782 That's because they have a class `box` applied to them, and in your CSS, you're applying `position: absolute;` to that box, which is taking the element out of the normal document flow and putting it at an exact coordinate location. So, naturally, any element with class `box` will have the same CSS properties applied to it, meaning here that any element with class `box` will appear in exactly the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

No need for drastic changes in HTML or even to add javascript. ;)

Instead of assigning CSS to `.opacity img:hover` try to assign it to `.opacity:hover img` like

```
    .opacity img { opacity:0.7; transition-duration: 0.5s; }

    .opacity:hover img { opacity:1; transition-duration: 1s; }

    .opacity img{ background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); -moz-transform: scale(0.9); -o-transform: scale(0.9); transform: scale(0.9); transition-duration: 0.5s; }

    .opacity:hover img{ background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.9); -webkit-transform: scale(1.0); -moz-transform: scale(1.0); -o-transform: scale(1.0); transform: scale(1.0); transition-duration: 0.5s; }
```

The effect is basically the same and the size stays while hovering the text (except for the gap between image and text). See the ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kysusekf/1/)***.